# SQL to select and order with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

In my current code,

```
$sql = "SELECT *, SUM(news_points.points) as `total`
CASE `total` WHEN 0 THEN ORDER BY `news_id` ASC
CASE `total` WHEN NOT 0 THEN ORDER BY `total` DESC
FROM `news`,`news_points`";
```

I have two tables, `news` and `news_points`. What I want to do is select `news` based on `news_points` column named `points`. If a `news` has no points or is negative put it below the "good" news, which are the ones that have positive points or atleast are not negative.

Some schema that might help.

```
news table

news_id -- news_title
  1 -- New publication available.
  2 -- Check out this new car!
  3 -- Something else.

news_points table

point_id -- news_id -- point
  1 -- 1 -- 2
  2 -- 1 -- 5
  3 -- 1 -- -4
  4 -- 2 -- 5
  5 -- 3 -- -2
```

Based on the example above. The news with `news_id=1` will have 3 points, `news_id=2` will have 5 points and `news_id=3` will have -2 points, therefore news with news_id 2 will be first, news with news_id 1 will be second and news_id will be last in the returned row. But if none of them have rating or only some, the rest just show in news_id descending.

How could I write this SQL to correctly get results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT news.*, SUM(news_points.points) as total
          FROM news left join news_points 
            ON news.news_id = news_points.news_id
          GROUP BY news.news_id
          ORDER BY total DESC, news.news_id ASC";
```

See, alsp, this **[short demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4b350/1)**.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! Will let me choose as an answer in 3 mins.

Comment: If you'll follow exactly OP's requirements *...the rest just show in news_id descending* that query won't produce required result. Example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c76/1. You'll have to use `CASE` to change the order for rows with total less or equal to `0`.

Comment: @peterm: If follow exactly OP's intent based on his original query attempts `CASE `total` WHEN 0 THEN ORDER BY `news_id` ASC` it seems rather probable (and more reasonable as well) that the sorting on 'news_id' be in ascending order.

Comment: The problem is that your query will sort by `news_id ASC` only when two or more rows have the same total (for both positive and negative total). One of the possible solutions http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4c76/3. Compare results of these two sqlfiddles.

Comment: @peterm: That is exactly what OP asked for. I don't see your point. According to OP only entries having no associated news_points should be ordered by `news_id`. I have no idea why you think entries with negative rating should be treated equally with entries with no rating.

Answer (score 1):

your question are little bit difficlult to understand. I tried my best check to see the result

```
 select news.news_id, sum(point) as sum, news.*  from 
news left join news_points on news.news_id= news_points.news_id
group by news.news_id order by sum desc
```

also see sql fiddle to your answer

[see you example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7769b/5/0)